# ¿Cómo alinear elementos en Relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Buenas, estoy haciendo este diseño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando trato de alinear título , precio y caja en mi RelativeLayout, pero todo se sobreprone

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Aquí mi codigo:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Titulo"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cajas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                android:text="cajas" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/precio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                 android:text="12 $"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="Titulo"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/cajas"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/title"
         android:text="cajas" />
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/precio"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/cajas"
         android:text="12 $"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

En esta caso utilizo `android:layout_below` para posicionar el elemento actual abajo del elemento que se referencia mediante su id. [Aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) puedes ver más opciones disponibles para posicionar elementos en un relativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

Elimina la propiedad android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" , ya que no es necesaria, en realidad estas acomodando los `TextView` a la derecha del `ImageView`, pero todos están dentro de un mismo `RelativeLayout`.

Para acomodar los `TextView` como lo indicas en tu imagen, usa la propiedad `android:layout_below` ,  para indicar abajo de que elemento posicionas la vista:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Titulo"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cajas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
            android:text="cajas" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/precio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cajas"
            android:text="12 $"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Esto para tener un resultado similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]